# Warning: An update to Formik inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, formik, react-testing-library

When I run my test it sends me a warning even if the test works. With some research it seems that I have to put it in an `act` but it is the same thing

```
console.error
    Warning: An update to Formik inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
       )

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:67:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:43:5)
      at warnIfNotCurrentlyActingUpdatesInDEV (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24064:9)
      at dispatch (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16135:9)
      at node_modules/formik/src/Formik.tsx:327:11

  console.error
    Warning: An update to Formik inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
```

```js
<div className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container alignItems="center" className={classes.h__full}>
                <Grid item sm={12} md={12} className={classes.w__full}>
                    <Alert
                        severity={message.status}
                        className={classes.alert}
                        style={{ visibility: message.message ? "visible" : "hidden" }}
                    >
                        {message.message}
                    </Alert>
                    <CreateSecretForm
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                        initialValues={initialValues}
                        validationSchema={CreateSecretSchema}
                    />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
```

[test code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkGLQ.png)

Why does this happen ?

Comment: Provide a minimal, reproducible, complete example

Answer (score 48, accepted):

https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/1543

Formik bug. In my case, this happened when running a jest test and it was related to `validateOnMount` property in Formik.
I fixed this by putting in a `waitFor` on my assertion:

```
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(getByText('Component header')).toBeInTheDocument()
    )
```

Note that wrapping the jest render in act does not work, as this is a rerender

Comment: This also works for same error with ANT Design components!

Comment: This doesn't work for all cases. For example, when trying to test for non submission.  Asserting `expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);` inside `waitFor` doesn't wait for anything since there is no error from the start.

Comment: This was the better answer: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1543#issuecomment-547501926

Comment: Adding `await act(() => Promise.resolve());` before assertions worked for me. Based on https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1543#issuecomment-1755444103.

Comment: @sammalfix worked for me too, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error while using @testing-library/react-native. What worked for me is

```
jest.useFakeTimers()
```

then after i change text I call

```
act(() => {
     jest.runAllTimers();
});
```

for example

```
    const textInput = getByA11yHint('Enter the text here');
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.changeText(textInput, 'test123');
    });

    act(() => {
      jest.runAllTimers();
    });
    expect(textInput.props.value).toBe('test123');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `expect(...)`: if the function passed to `expect` returns an *(E.g.)* `HTMLElement`, look for an alternative which returns a `Promise<HTMLElement>`.

Here is an example which worked for me:

```
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react"

test('test name', async () => {
    /*something else here ...*/

    // expect(screen.getByRole( ... )).toBeEnabled() // before
    expect( await screen.findByRole( ... )).toBeEnabled() // after
})
```

Note that `screen.getByRole` returns an `HTMLElement`, whereas `screen.findByRole` returns a `Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this around your code:

```
await act(async() => {
  ...
});
```

See this example from [this comment](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1543#issuecomment-547501926) in the issue [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68891807/586000) by [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10375291/tom-nelson)

```
await act(async() => {
fireEvent.change(getByLabelText(/email/i), {target: {value: fakeUsername}}); });
```